Problem with Visual Studio "The process cannot access the file... because it is being used by another process"
I have a Winforms app project in Visual Studio 2022 and every time I edit the code or the designer and try to run the app, I get this error:

Error MSB3021
Unable to copy file "X:\School Projects\Hotel-Reservation-Demo\Hotel-Reservation\Hotel-Res\obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\apphost.exe" to "bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\Hotel-Res.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\Hotel-Res.exe' because it is being used by another process.
Hotel-Res X:\Program\Visual Studio\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  5167

and:

Error MSB3027
Could not copy "X:\School Projects\Hotel-Reservation-Demo\Hotel-Reservation\Hotel-Res\obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\apphost.exe" to "bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\Hotel-Res.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. The file is locked by: "Hotel-Res (22108)"
Hotel-Res X:\Program\Visual Studio\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  5167

The only solution I found at this moment is to open the task manager and close "Hotel-Res" and then it run, but not every time I find it there. I tried on other desktops and the problem is there too.

I would guess your program has a bug. However you are closing it doesn't actually cause the program to exit.

You could look at the answer to check if your program has the related code that may cause the IO exception.

I have a similar issue here in that some references take a while to unlock.

This can also be caused by some anti-malware scanning your executable.

you could include a kill switch in your code to stop any other instances running when its reloaded (or only allow one instance of the program to run at anytime)

The issue is that when Windows programs are running their EXE files become locked until the program unloads. This error is a sign that the program is not unloaded (is running), and of course you would need to terminate the program to unload it and free locks on the EXE file.
Typically you would launch your application from within the IDE by pressing F5 or the Play icon to launch the application under the debugger. Once the application terminates, or you press the Stop icon, the application should unload and the EXE file should be released.
Use the debugger to launch and shutdown the application and this should not be a problem. In some rare scenarios you may need to launch an application externally, but 99.999% of the time you should be launching under a debugger.
If launching it manually, you need a way to exit the application between runs. For services this is usually a Service Control STOP request (sc.exe under Windows, systemctl under Linux, launchctl under macOS) -- if a STOP request is not shutting down the application as expected it would most likely be caused by a bug in the program, such as spawning a thread without configuring it as a "background" thread (the ideal thread option), allowing it to hold the application open until all non-background threads exit.

It sounds like you are trying to run a new instance of your program before stopping your current instance. This isn't possible because you can't overwrite the exe file while it's being used.
If you are wanting live updates while the program is running then you are probably looking for functionality of "hot reloading".
Also worth noting that if my original sentence is incorrect, then you could be having policies or an antivirus on your device that scan newly created executable.

Since the path of the program starts with the drive name "X", I think that the program execution path is probably the network path or the mapped drive or "Ram Drive".
If so, I suggest running the program from a short path on a normal drive (local HDD or SSD) and see if the problem still occurs? For example, the following path:
D:\[Projects]\Hotel-Reservation

Microsoft explains Here that "Error MSB3027" may occur for the following reasons:

"Typical causes include the destination file is in use by another
program, the permissions to not allow writing to the destination file,
not enough space on the drive, or the network drive is not available
due to a network or permissions error."

Maybe the issue is due to one of the packages installed in the project:

A question was posted on
learn.microsoft.com
about "Errors MSB3027 and MSB3021", and people said that the path length of the program (or
the packages of that program) may be long. Of course, this has
happened in that question for the MAUI project.

Also check the "post-build events" section in the project so that if the copy operation is defined, it will never access the unreachable path due to various conditions.
There is another possibility:
If sometimes a "Windows service" based on one of the files in bin\Debug is started simultaneously by the program, it may not necessarily be stopped when the program is stopped.

The issue is you have another instance of your application already running. Ensure that you have exited the previous instance of your application before trying to start another one.
If you have closed it but are still experiencing the issue, it's possible the application hasn't finished shutting. This may be due to some long running tasks that have not been handled properly.
Alternatively, if you have a plugin that automatically runs unit tests like NCrunch or ReSharper, this could be accessing the EXE file for your application and locking it. You may need to temporarily stop them while debugging or investigate configuration changes that would prevent them from locking your EXE file.

Disable Parallel Build:
Parallel builds can cause conflicts. You can disable it by going to Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run and setting the "maximum number of parallel project builds" to 1.
Increase Retry Count:
You can try increasing the retry count for file copies in your .csproj file. Although this doesn't directly fix the problem, it might give the system enough time to release the file:
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyRetryCount>20</CopyRetryCount>
</PropertyGroup>

Disable Application Insights or Diagnostic Tools:
If you're using Application Insights or other diagnostic tools, they might be causing the lock. Try disabling them temporarily.
Set CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies to False:
If you're using .NET Core or .NET 5+, you can try setting CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies to false in your project file:
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>false</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>

Check for Open File Handles:
You can use the handle.exe tool from Sysinternals to check which process is locking the file. Run handle.exe  in Command Prompt to see which process is holding the file open.
